# Calculate SVD on a TF-IDF matrix

Tags: python, tf-idf, svd

I want to perform Singular Value Decomposition on a TF-IDF matrix. But the TF-IDF matrix gives me something like this (index of term,score):

```
[(1,0.2) , (2,0.3) , (6,0.1) ...]
[(3,0.2) , (5,0.3) , (10,0.1) ...]
```

So the code `u,s,v = svd(corpus_tfidf)` will not work on it. 
I want a TF-IDF matrix that only has scores, not terms indices.

I have calculated TF-IDF like this:

```
tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus)
corpus_tfidf=tfidf[corpus]
```

Comment: you are applied? in what way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use gensim for tfidf generation, you can use matutils to convert your tfidf representation to dense numpy ndarray and vice versa.

```
from gensim import matutils
tfidf_dense = matutils.corpus2dense(corpus_tfidf, num_terms).T
```

where num_terms is a number of unique terms in your corpus. It can be calculated this way:

```
num_terms = len(corpus_tfidf.obj.idfs)
```